# Find Last Row in Table and paste

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that i am running to copy and paste into a tabele **(Table1)**.
I keep getting a error each i run the code, can you advise on the error on my code?

```
Sub CopyData1()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Sheets("Tracker").ListObjects("Table1")
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C1").Copy Destination:=tbl.Range("C").Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 End With
End Sub
```

The objective of the macro is to paste in the next avaible row.

Comment: Is "C" the name of the column in the table, or just the column letter?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor both arguments for offset are actually optional.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor  Column 3 is the name of column

Comment: Okay, my bad been wasting characters for time then haha... comment deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will paste "C1" to the next available row in "Table1" object (in "Sheet1"), at column "C":

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData1()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim LastRow As Long

Set tbl = Sheets("Tracker").ListObjects("Table1")
LastRow = tbl.Range.Rows.Count ' get number of rows in "Table1" object

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C1").Copy Destination:=tbl.Range(LastRow, "C").Offset(1)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this pastes at the end of the table , not on the next avaiable row. Unless i am doing something wrong

Comment: @James Why do you have blank rows in your table?

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you very much the issue was that i also had blank rows in my table

Comment: this assumes the table's first row is row 1, if the table is not at the top of the worksheet, you need to add an offset

Comment: @Yuca why is it an assumption? If you read the post, you can see in his code that's where the table starts. About 99.99% of the time, Tables (ListObjects) will be located at the first row.

Comment: The contents of what you copy are on row 1 no? you have no idea of the table's position IIUC

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to correctly add data to the first empty row of the table or add data if the table is empty. Found an easy solution which works for both cases:

```
LastRow = yoursheet.ListObjects("yourtable").Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1, 0).Row
```